# Limit access to method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have made a custom-attribute that you can use to decorate your methods in your Controller.

I also have a method in my service-layer that only should be accessed from controller method that are decoraded with my attribute. Is this possible to do?

Example

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    // Should be allowed to call the method below
    _service.GetWeatherInfo();
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    // Should NOT be allowed to call the method below
    _service.GetWeatherInfo(); // This should not be accessible here
}
```

Comment: Not with C# as-is, no. You could enforce something like this with a Roslyn analyzer.

Comment: You can load the stack trace, then see what function called your function and check via reflection if it has the attribute. But this would check during runtime and not during compile-time.

Comment: While you could use a Roslyn analyser to enforce this, it seems a little extreme. Why do you think restricting this method is a good idea in the first place?

Comment: @DavidG: It was just a thought i had i mind. But I will find another solution for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to do something like that you could try the below, though it's not very good because it only works with one controller at the moment. If you have no experience with ASP I would say to look at the [Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attribute and then only call your service method from actions decorated with a certain policy.

```
public void GetWeatherInfo([CallerMemberName] string methodName = null)
{
    var hasAttribute = typeof(WeatherController).GetMethod(methodName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true).Any();

    if(!hasAttribute)
         throw new Exception("Forbidden");
}
```

Comment: This assumes it only comes from a single controller, so the attribute is essentially pointless.

Comment: It's also a violation of SOLID principals. The service should never know about the controller. Sorry, but I'm going to have to downvote this.